# Gradle error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Adding implementation project(':mylibrary') in app's build.gradle generates below error.

```
:mylibrary:generateDebugSources
                \generated\source\r\debug\myapp\example\com\mylibrary\R.java:775: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
    public static int alternates_for_albanian_ï¿½ = 0x7f15001e;                                                                  
                                               ^
                \build\generated\source\r\debug\myapp\example\com\mylibrary\R.java:775: error: illegal character: '\ufffd'
    public static int alternates_for_albanian_? = 0x7f15001e;
                                              ^
    1 error

    :mylibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':mylibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

However, if we use the same string directly in app's resource file, I don't get this error, as soon as I move this string statement in library module resource file and then add the library compile dependency in app's build.gradle file it gives me error for unmappable character.

Comment: **`error: illegal character: '\ufffd'`** check out the albanian string resources for the illegal string.

Comment: <string name="alternates_for_albanian_ë">ë?¿</string> this is the string which I am using, While using in app resource I am not getting the error, however if I move this in a library module resource file, it gives me error.

Comment: If I add a JVM propery -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in gradle.properties, this error gets resolved. What is the root cause of this issue?

Comment: It seems like it is an unknown or illegal character for UTF-8 encoding. That's why you get the error.

Comment: No this issue is happening when i am upgrading my gradle version to 3.1.4 , presently I am using 2.2.4 and moreover this happens only if this string resource is placed in a different module rather than the app module.